# C# Performance of classes with generics

Tags: c#, performance, class, generics

Consider a set of elements that derive from a base element.

```
// "Abstract" general element class
class AElement {
  public int Key;
}

// Specific element class implementation
class BElement : AElement {
}
```

That I want to store in a list. The two options:

```
List<AElement> aData = new List<AElement>();
List<BElement> bData = new List<BElement>();
```

If adding BElement's to both the aData and bData lists, and doing operations on the two, the bData version is significantly faster than the aData version. For example if using a dump generic BubbleSort, sorting of the "Key" of AElement:

```
static void BubbleSort<TElement>(List<TElement> Data) where TElement : AElement {
  for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)  {
    for (int j = 0; j < Data.Count; j++)  {
      if (Data[i].Key< Data[j].Key)         {
        TElement tmp = Data[i];
        Data[i] = Data[j];
        Data[j] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case with 5000 data elements I see up to 20% difference in favor of the bData compared to the aData.

Why is the bData faster than the aData here?

Edit: Added complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TemplateClassPerformance
{
  class Program {

    // "Abstract" general element class
    class AElement {
      public int Index;
    }

    // Specific element class implementation
    class BElement : AElement { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Random random = new Random();
      Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        List<AElement> aData = new List<AElement>();
        List<BElement> bData = new List<BElement>();

        // Put the same elements in both lists
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
          BElement element = new BElement();
          element.Index = random.Next(1000000);
          aData.Add(element);
          bData.Add(element);
        }

        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        BubbleSort(bData);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        long sbTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        BubbleSort(aData);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        long saTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

        Console.Out.WriteLine("sb: {0}, sa: {1}", sbTicks, saTicks);
      }
    }

    static void BubbleSort<TElement>(List<TElement> data) where TElement : AElement {
      for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data.Count; j++) {
          if (data[i].Index < data[j].Index)   {
            TElement tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = tmp;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How long is it taking with 5000 elements? How are you ensuring the fairness of your benchmark? Can you post the complete benchmark code?

Comment: I just tried it, and found no difference in speed. Most likely you made some mistake in you benchmark, such as not accounting for warmup. And you should use a release build without a debugger attached.

Comment: And 5k elements is a bit low for a benchmark. That takes only 0.1 seconds on my comp. Try it with 50k elements, that should give a better result averaging out some random fluctuations and warmup.

Comment: I reproduced the results on my machine, and I'm not sure why the results are what they are...

Answer (score 2):

1. Public fields are not a good idea.
2. Bubble sort is not a very good bench-mark
3. It is still a strange result. Did you eliminate JIT and GC effects? Ran the tests multiple times in different order?  Did you use the Stopwatch?

> Why is the bData faster than the aData here?

Answer: It shouldn't be. I'm suspecting some measurement artefact.

---

#### Edit, after seeing the full code:

There is a difference, and I can't fault the benchmarking. So there is something to this.

When I change the initialization to :

```
int k = random.Next(1000000);
aData.Add(new AElement() { Index = k });
bData.Add(new BElement() { Index = k });
```

The difference goes away. But I realize this is not a complete answer.

Comment: 1. The public field is to eliminate any overhead related to the class.
2. Bubble sort was arbitrarily chosen as a method for accessing the list
3. I run the test in a loop 10 times, and results are reproducable

Comment: Can you post the benchmarking code?  It seems more likely to be the source of the results than the 2 classes. See the comment from @CodeinC

Comment: Then please post a compilable code that exhibits the behavior. I could find no difference in my test.

Comment: Comment to the edit: This is what it is all about: Why is it slower when the list contains element that are not of type of the list, but of an inherited type.

Comment: @Jesper: But you jump the gun by attributing it to generics. Try it with an array first. This has something to do with either co/contra variance or inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
      BElement element = new BElement();
      element.Index = random.Next(1000000);
      aData.Add(element);
      bData.Add(element);
    }
```

with:

```
int index_;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
      BElement belement = new BElement();
      AElement aelement = new AElement();
      index_=random.Next(1000000);
      Belement.Index =Aelement.Index = index_;
      aData.Add(Aelement);
      bData.Add(Belement);
    }
```

And report the result.